# How to create login through navigation bar instead of page

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm currently programming a simple website that'll be view able for both logged in users, and non-logged in users.

I am able to create a simple login page using spring/spring-security, but i'd much rather allow logins through the navigation bar (like on facebook). Would this be possible with spring-security? It appears that spring-security only allows logins from login pages, rather then from a block of html inside an html page.

Edit: I'm thinking about using a success handler and just making it update the page after the login is finished rather then redirecting.

Comment: How do you know that facebook is using spring security?

Comment: I don't. I'm simply giving an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: your question is not very clear about what you want to do. You can definitely use navber to put your login form. it has nothing to do with spring security

Comment: Foremost, if you want to use Facebook concept (i.e. single page application), use event-driven flow on the front end instead of MVC. For this purpose would recommend you Freemarker rather Thymeleaf as template engine, and React.js rather than Angular.js. Of course, tech stack is up to you, but those are most novel technology and easy to use. Also, to implement state pattern you will need some library, [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/).Finally, configure

Comment: ...Finally, configure **WebSecurityConfiguration** class which extends **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter **. I would add there anonymous authentication and used URL's parent directory path in the method .formLogin("/"). First time to implement event-driven approach would be a bit tricky, at least for me, but after you will feel the the power of that approach.

Comment: If any of the answer have helped you please accept it to point out the correct solution!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but you have to use AJAX if you want to auto-reload the page.
If you are using Spring's Java Configuration you can configure it the following:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(this.csrfTokenRepository())
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    /* The configuration of which requests to intercept. */
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login/failed")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/o")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login/out")
                    .permitAll();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a {@link CsrfTokenRepository} that sets the token name to
     * _csrf.
     *
     * @return The {@link CsrfTokenRepository}.
     */
    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        val csrfTokenRepository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        csrfTokenRepository.setSessionAttributeName("_csrf");
        return csrfTokenRepository;
    }
}
```

The configuration above does the following:

- Configures the CSRF token repository to accept the CSRF token on a parameter named `_csrf`. (More about CSRF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery
- Sets the login page to be available on `/login`.
- Sets the login processing URL to `/login`. This is the URL you have to send POST requests to with the username, the password, and the CSRF token set.
- Sets the failure URL to `/login/failed`. This is the page a user gets redirected to when he enters wrong credentials on the login page.
- Configures the parameters for the username and the password to be `username` and `password`. These are the parameters you have to set along with your CSRF token in the POST request you send to the login processing URL.
- Permits all accesses on the login page.
- Configures the logout URL and the logout successful URL.

---

That is mostly everything you have to do on the server side. On the client side, you either have to configure a form with the action set to the login processing URL and the method set to POST and a hidden field with the name `_csrf` which contains the CSRF token or you have to send an AJAX request like that.

Greetings, Fabian

---

I have done that before so here is a working example of how to use it: https://github.com/lcmanager/gdb

The Spring Web Configuration: https://github.com/lcmanager/gdb/blob/master/gdb-web-control/src/main/java/org/lcmanager/gdb/config/WebSecurityConfiguration.java

A form to log in: https://github.com/lcmanager/gdb/blob/master/gdb-web-control/src/main/resources/templates/modules/login.ftl

And login via JavaScript (using AngularJS): https://github.com/lcmanager/gdb/blob/master/gdb-web-control/src/main/resources/static/js/modules/login.js